# displaying an image on html with a json file

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to store an image in a json object and display it on a html page with the rest of the data in the object. The image is stored locally in a folder called images. I have some code, but it doesnt seem to work... Can anyone please advise?

Comment: You don't show how you call `populateContent`. May you do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"photo":"<img src=images/audir8.jpg"`

their is missing a closing ">" tag

Answer (score 0):

Update you json like this

```
{
        "id":2,
        "name":"Audi A4",
        "make":"Audi",
        "model":"A4",
        "enginesize":"1968cc",
        "power":"140 BHP",
        "acceleration":"7.8 seconds",
        "topspeed":"139 MPH",
        "drivetrain":"Front-wheel drive",
        "specification":"Sat Nav, Heated Seats, Convertible, Immobiliser, Traction Control, Metallic paint, Airbags, LED lights",
        "photo":"images/audir8.jpg"
    }
```

html

```
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<ul>

    <h2>Performance</h2>


<ul id="make"></ul>
<ul id="model"></ul>
<ul id="enginesize"></ul>
<ul id="power"></ul>
<ul id="acceleration"></ul>
<ul id="topspeed"></ul>
<ul id="drivetrain"></ul>
<ul id="specification"></ul>
<ul ><img id="photo" />
 </ul>
    </ul>
<script src="js/details.js"></script>

</div>

     </div>
```

javascript

```
function populateContent(car)

{

    titleEl=document.getElementById("title");
    makeEL=document.getElementById("make");
    modelEl=document.getElementById("model");
    enginesizeEl=document.getElementById("enginesize");
    powerEl=document.getElementById("power");
    accelerationEl=document.getElementById("acceleration");
    topspeedEl=document.getElementById("topspeed");
    drivetrainEl=document.getElementById("drivetrain");
    specificationEl=document.getElementById("specification");
    photoEl=document.getElementById("photo");
    //document.getElementById("imageid").src="../images/audir8.png";



    titleEl.innerHTML = car.name;
    makeEL.innerHTML = "<b>Make: </b>"+car.make;
    modelEl.innerHTML = "<b>Model: </b>"+car.model;
    enginesizeEl.innerHTML = "<b>Engine Size: </b>"+car.enginesize;
    powerEl.innerHTML = "<b>Power: </b>"+car.power;
    accelerationEl.innerHTML = "<b>0-60: </b>"+car.acceleration;
    topspeedEl.innerHTML = "<b>Top Speed: </b>"+car.topspeed;
    drivetrainEl.innerHTML = "<b>Drivetrain: </b>"+car.drivetrain;
    specificationEl.innerHTML = "<h2>Specification: </h2>"+car.specification;
    photoEl.src= car.photo;


}
```

Comment: The HTML is also invalid (`ul` can _only_ have `li` as children).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing of image tag `/>`. Add that and it will work. For demonstration I have used a live URL for the image. You can replace that with yours. Also, `<ul>` has `<li>` elements so replace that too.

```js
var jsonData = {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Audi A4",
    "make":"Audi",
    "model":"A4",
    "enginesize":"1968cc",
    "power":"140 BHP",
    "acceleration":"7.8 seconds",
    "topspeed":"139 MPH",
    "drivetrain":"Front-wheel drive",
    "specification":"Sat Nav, Heated Seats, Convertible, Immobiliser, Traction Control, Metallic paint, Airbags, LED lights",
    "photo":"<img src=http://myanmareiti.org/sites/default/files/styles/medium_retina/public/sample-5_0.jpg?itok=wn8qRWZM />"
};
function populateContent(car)
{
  titleEl=document.getElementById("title");
  makeEL=document.getElementById("make");
  modelEl=document.getElementById("model");
  enginesizeEl=document.getElementById("enginesize");
  powerEl=document.getElementById("power");
  accelerationEl=document.getElementById("acceleration");
  topspeedEl=document.getElementById("topspeed");
  drivetrainEl=document.getElementById("drivetrain");
  specificationEl=document.getElementById("specification");
  photoEl=document.getElementById("photo");
  //document.getElementById("imageid").src="../images/audir8.png";



  titleEl.innerHTML = car.name;
  makeEL.innerHTML = "<b>Make: </b>"+car.make;
  modelEl.innerHTML = "<b>Model: </b>"+car.model;
  enginesizeEl.innerHTML = "<b>Engine Size: </b>"+car.enginesize;
  powerEl.innerHTML = "<b>Power: </b>"+car.power;
  accelerationEl.innerHTML = "<b>0-60: </b>"+car.acceleration;
  topspeedEl.innerHTML = "<b>Top Speed: </b>"+car.topspeed;
  drivetrainEl.innerHTML = "<b>Drivetrain: </b>"+car.drivetrain;
  specificationEl.innerHTML = "<h2>Specification: </h2>"+car.specification;
  photoEl.innerHTML = "<h2>photo: </h2>"+car.photo;
}

populateContent(jsonData);
```

```html
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<ul>

<h2>Performance</h2>
  <li id="make"></li>
  <li id="model"></li>
  <li id="enginesize"></li>
  <li id="power"></li>
  <li id="acceleration"></li>
  <li id="topspeed"></li>
  <li id="drivetrain"></li>
  <li id="specification"></li>
  <li id="photo"></li>
</ul>
```